# Постепенный вывод букв

Tags: c#

Всем привет, вот смотрите на этот код

```
textBox1.Text = "Привет";
```

А можно ли например при помощи таймера сделать так(к примеру интервал 5 сек)

Первый раз таймер сработал

- Добавилась буква "П"

Второй раз таймер сработал

- Добавилась буква "р"

Ну и.т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
var str = "Привет";
var dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += delegate { if(i<str.length){ textBox1.Text += str[i]; i++; } };
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,3);
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```